# nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Since a while ago, I've been receiving the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:81 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:81 failed (98: Unknown error)

(the above repeats 5 times)

nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

**I only have two configs setup for nginx:**

```
root@YumYummity:/# sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

site1.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name beta.DOMAIN.TLD;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

and site2.conf

```
server {
    listen 81;
    listen [::]:81 ipv6only=on;
    server_name DOMAIN.TLD;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

**Hardware Info:**

```
root@YumYummity:/# hostnamectl
 Static hostname: YumYummity
       Icon name: computer-vm
         Chassis: vm
      Machine ID: 6f2d2e6f6e3e444c9dc7b36422cc2803
         Boot ID: 16bcf7164313496ca23ee6cf51a04394
  Virtualization: microsoft
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
          Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-86-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: Vultr
  Hardware Model: HFC
```

**I've tried the following commands:**
(I try to start nginx afterwards)

```
sudo reboot
sudo systemctl stop nginx
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp (and 81/tcp)
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo killall nginx
```

I do not use certbot, apache, or NPM.

**I have checked my ports 80 and 81:**

```
root@YumYummity:/# sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      714/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      846/postgres
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      793/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      760/memcached
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      846/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      793/sshd: /usr/sbin
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           714/systemd-resolve
udp        0      0 censored_ip:68         0.0.0.0:*                           712/systemd-network
```

And checking with lsof: (same result with 81)

```
root@YumYummity:/# sudo lsof -i:80
root@YumYummity:/#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing the port 80, it'd fail to connect.
However, after I uninstalled nginx, I tried accessing the port again and apparently apache2 was somehow installed.

This is highly unusual because:

1. nginx worked in the past
2. I can't seem to uninstall it:

```bash
root@YumYummity:~# sudo apt-get remove apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'apache2' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 121 not upgraded.
root@YumYummity:~# ^C
root@YumYummity:~# sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 121 not upgraded.
root@YumYummity:~# ^C
root@YumYummity:~# sudo apt remove apache2.*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'apache2.2-common' for glob 'apache2.*'
Note, selecting 'apache2.2-bin' for glob 'apache2.*'
Package 'apache2.2-bin' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'apache2.2-common' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 121 not upgraded.
root@YumYummity:~#
```

My Solution:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2*
```

This removed all traces of apache2 from my system.